# Problems with certain type conversions in c++

Tags: c++

I am using box2d(however this question is probably only about c++ itself) and there is a member variable which is pointer to void, like this:

```
void* userData;
```

You can get the userData by the getUserData(), which returns a a void pointer.

I want to store a string as the userData and there is set the userData to the string like so:

```
std::string user = "player";
playerDef.userData = &user;
```

Then I am trying to get the userData by doing this:

```
std::string* sd = (std::string*)bb->GetUserData();
```

(where "bb" is a pointer to the entity holding these information)

Finally, I try to use the function c_str() in order to get what is compatible for my purposes but then I get the error:
*Access violation reading location 0x00000070*

I also want to be able to do the same thing but with a char array but I am doing this:

```
char user[] = "player";
playerDef.userData = &user;

char* sd[] = (char*)bb->GetUserData();
```

The third step gives the error: 
*Cannot convert from 'char*' to 'char*[]'*

I could already feel by looking at this approach on the char part that something was wrong but I do not know what...

I did the same thing with integers like this:

```
int user[] = int;
playerDef.userData = &user;

int* sd = (int*)bb->GetUserData();
```

and that worked just great.

So my questions are the following:

- What am I doing wrong with the std::string part?
- What is wrong with the char part and how to achieve the char array
  that I want?
- How come that the integer part works then :/ (I know that it is not an array though)?

Note: I would be more than happy to get extra thoughts on possible optimizations in general, like user static_cast or something.

Thanks! It is really appreciated, like very much!

Cheers.

Comment: I suspect you're trying to save a pointer to a local string, which is destroyed when the scope ends.

Comment: Use a dynamically-allocated string and you should be OK.

Comment: If that's not it, you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ïnteger part is different from char part. Note `char* sd[]` vs `int* sd`

Comment: `and that worked just great.` -- If your `int` version is similar to your `string` version, it isn't really working great if it is a local array.

Comment: Please post real code, not "something like this" followed by a bunch of errors. Nobody knows what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string user = "player";
playerDef.userData = &user;
```

When whatever function sets this pointer here returns, `user`, the `std::string` object, gets destroyed. The fact that there's a pointer to this `std::string`, somewhere, doesn't change that.

Your subsequent attempt to use this pointer fails miserably, since, obviously, the string has been destroyed, and the pointer points to garbage.

And when you use an `int` array, that was broken also. The fact that your program didn't crash in that case doesn't change that this was undefined behavior, and a bug.

This is a common situation when integrating C++ code with a generic C library, that knows nothing about C++ classes, where all that it offers you to work with is an opaque, bland `void` pointer. There are several ways of doing this correctly. A common way is to use dynamic scope:

```
playerDef.userData = new std::string;
*playerDef.userData = "player";
```

Later you can dereference this pointer, having some degree of confidence that the pointed-to object still exist, and hasn't been nuked from high orbit.

Of course, now you will need to make sure that at some point this is going to get `delete`d, otherwise you'll leak memory. But this is often the best that can be done when working with a C library's opaque pointers.